# how to detect dates with openNLP

Tags: java, date, opennlp, sentence

I want to detect dates on a sentence by using openNLP. It's easy to use id there is a existing model other than training by myslft. Can anyone please guide me how to do it in java.

Answer (score 3):

- First download `Date name finder model` from [here](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/) (English version- en tag)
- Also download `Tokenizer model`. Because input for Name Finder Model should be tokenized array
- Add them into project folder or somewhere else

> **Load both model**

```
InputStream modelIn1 = new FileInputStream("en-ner-date.bin");
InputStream modelIn2 = new FileInputStream("en-token.bin");
```

**Create Tokenizer model and NamefinderModel**

```
try {
  TokenizerModel model1 = new TokenizerModel(modelIn2);
  TokenNameFinderModel model2 = new TokenNameFinderModel(modelIn1);
}
catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
  if (modelIn1 != null) {
    try {
      modelIn1.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
  if (modelIn2 != null) {
    try {
      modelIn2.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

**Then Load TokenizerME and NameFinderME**

```
Tokenizer tokenizer = new TokenizerME(model1);
NameFinderME nameFinder = new NameFinderME(model2);
```

**Then get tokens from tokenizer model**

```
String tokens[] = tokenizer.tokenize("An input sample sentence.");
```

**Then send this token array as a parameter to namefinder model**

```
Span nameSpans[] = nameFinder.find(tokens);
```

**This will convert it to array of predicted dates as string**

```
String[] array=Span.spansToStrings(nameSpans,tokens);
```